# How to execute code after the response for a XHR request (sent by the page itself, having a URL which matches a given regex) is received

Tags: javascript, regex, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I've written a Greasemonkey [userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14036-kat-add-approve-all-and-approve-selected-buttons-to-feedback-popup) for kat.cr that adds a few extra buttons  inside the 'Torrents awaiting feedback' popup.

The procedure is this:
(provided that you have login and that you have some downloaded some torrents that "await feedback") :
whenever you click the FEEDBACK button,
a spinning icon appears, and, during that time, an XHR request(*) is sent by the page itself.
When the response arrives, the FEEDBACK popup appears showing the torrents that await feedback.

*(*) The regex that matches the XHR URL -as shown in 'Network' DevTool of Firefox-

is `https:\/\/kastatic.com\/js\/xhr.*`*

*I currently use `setTimeout` to insert delay (0.5 sec) until after the popup is displayed*
*but unfortunately this doesn't work all the time if the XHR response takes more time to be received*

I want to improve the script,
i.e. to add the buttons **after** the response for the XHR request is received.*
**How can I do this?** *(unfortunately I don't have a clue on how is that even possible)*

Comment: Who is making XHR call? Where is that part of code?

Comment: Does it use a JS library for the Ajax call?

Comment: Clicking on the 'ev' icon on the FEEDBACK button (in Firefox Inspector), it shows that the relevant code is `f = p.handle = function(e) {
  return typeof t !== c && (!e || t.event.triggered !== e.type) ? t.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem, arguments) : i
}` which is located in this file `https://kastatic.com/js/all-261c451.js` (which is minified). And, here are the page sources shown in the Debugger: https://i.imgur.com/x8pM1Do.jpg.  Unfortunately I can't provide you any more info